# Absolute element within relative parent with max-width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position `#header-supporter` on the bottom right of `#header-image` (overlapping). The difficult part is doing so by setting a `max-width` of 1280px on `#header-supporter-cont` to make it consistent with the rest of the site margin.

I've tried placing `#header-supporter` directly within `#header`, but then I can't use `max-width` because `#header-image` needs to be full-width.

Here is my markup:

```
  <header id="header">
    <div id="header-image">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=44&txt=Header&w=1920&h=200" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="header-supporter-cont">
      <div id="header-supporter">
        <div>
          Lead Supporter
        </div>
        <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&w=65&h=65" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Here's a Pen: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/ObBWaY.

Comment: What is the reason for having a max-width on the header support?

Comment: If you want an element to take it's position in relation to another, it needs to be a **child** of the relative parent. You'll need to restructure the HTML.

Comment: @Adjit So that I can simply say `right: 0` and it'll align with the rest of the site margin, and not go to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, I'm aware, but I don't think you understand my problem

Comment: If an absolute element is a child of a relative element, saying `right: 0` will do the same thing. Without the need for setting max width. It will never extend beyond the bounds of the parent, relative, element

Comment: @Adjit If it were behaving this way, I wouldn't be here. My issue is setting the absolute child's parent to relative *and* a max-width.

Comment: But you shouldn't need to set the max width for the margins if the parent element has those margins

Comment: Like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eBPvOW ...No?

Comment: @Adjit Right, but as I explained, I can't set a max-width on the `#header` parent, and setting the `#header-supporter` parent as relative prevents me from setting its max-width

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, but *overlapping* the header image.

Comment: The just adjust the `top` value or use negative margins

Comment: @Paulie_D It's already at 0, but I was trying to avoid using a negative margin

Comment: Change the top value to a negative value.....same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setted a position: relative on #header-supporter-cont, and bottom instead of top on #header-supporter

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENdWgE

```
 #header-supporter-cont {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
  position: relative;

  #header-supporter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mind you want it on bottom, now is correct :)